# Find matching keywords in a text (for parsing a link)

Tags: sql-server, parsing, text, match, keyword

*"It is my first question here, so if any fault while asking a question,sorry firstly."*

> **TableA** (have 200k rows)
>
> ---
>
> **id**       **text**                                         **keywords**
>   101     24hourdelivery                           NULL
>   102     carracing                                    NULL
>   103     dailynews                                   NULL
>   104     livescores                                   NULL
>   105     worldcup                                     NULL

-

> **TableB** (have 400k rows)
>
> ---
>
> **id**       **length**       **keywords**
>   101     4               hour
>   102     8               delivery
>   103     3               car
>   104     6               racing
>   105     5               daily
>   106     4               news
>   107     4               live
>   108     6               scores
>   109     5               world
>   110     3               cup

-

I will run a sql once a day and get the keywords updated in TableA.
There will be everyday **different** 200k rows in TableA
It will look like that (keywords ordered by their length):

> **TableA**
>
> ---
>
> **id**       **text**                                         **keywords**
>   101     24hourdelivery                       #delivery#hour#24#
>   102     carracing                                #racing#car#
>   103     dailynews                               #daily#news#new#
>   104     livescores                               #scores#score#live#
>   105     worldcup                                 #world#cup#

---

i tried to do with **MERGE**

```
MERGE INTO TableA As T  
USING (SELECT keywords FROM TABLEB order by length desc) As S  
ON CHARINDEX(S.keywords,T.text)>0
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET keywords=keywords+'#'+S.keywords;
```

1-there were an error about that i cant use **order by** with MERGE (i replaced it)
2-**"The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE the same row more than once.."**

---

Any solution?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `MERGE` doesn't, as it says, let you alter the same record twice during the same execution. Thus, you can't update a record to reflect finding a match, then do it again. To do exactly what you're asking, my best suggestion would be something like a cursor, but that would be insanely slow.

Without knowing details of what you're hoping to actually do with your data, I'd start off with suggesting that you pull your currently-hashtag-delimited data out into a separate table, or even a view. Again, I don't know what you're doing with it, so that could be wrong. But in most cases that's what I'd suggest. Particularly since you're talking about the data changing every day anyway. That'll be the lightest overhead in most cases, and it'll be easier to work with.

If you were to take that approach, your view could be defined with something like

```
SELECT TableA.*, TableB.Id AS BId, TableB.Keywords AS Keywords
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON (TableA.Text LIKE '%' + TableB.Keywords + '%')
```

You just told me in a comment that you're actually adding another 200,000 records a day. I misunderstood that originally. This will likely not be particularly fast given that.

I would still invest in a separate table, though. Again, without knowing specific details of what you're hoping to accomplish, that seems easier. You could just run the following statement when you import data:

```
INSERT INTO [TableName] (AId, BId)
SELECT TableA.Id, TableB.Id
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON (TableA.Text LIKE '%' + TableB.Keywords + '%')
```

Again, that just seems like it would be easier to manipulate, particularly in that you don't have to parse out the hashtag symbols to read what keywords were present, or even how many were. You could also use the `MERGE` if you wanted here, rather than doing an `INSERT`. You could even make use of `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` and keep it properly synchronized. And you could use a trigger if that was beneficial.

The choice between doing a table like this or a view is really just a matter of performance requirements, each will be better in certain circumstances.

I'll alter this answer if you'd rather not take that approach, since I know this doesn't strictly answer the question you actually posted. But I'm taking it a bit of a different direction and making this suggestion.

Comment: The whole data wont change everyday, everyday will be **another** new 100-200k entries. and i will do the same operation for that new entries everyday! i want to parse links to keywords, i will use that in domaining project. Thanks

Comment: Ohh, my apologies. I misunderstood. I'll delete my answer and try and think up a better one. :)

Comment: @G.KISA I edited my answer. Does that sound more reasonable? Again, I know I'm not really *answering your question*, per se. So please, tell me if I'm taking you in a completely wrong direction. This just seems like it has every advantage over storing the data separately in a varchar column.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your code insert a row, for all keywords, when i ran it, it looks like that: [text:24hourdelivery keywords:24]  [text:24hourdelivery keywords:hour]  [text:24hourdelivery keywords:delivery] there makes 3rows. i only want one row to include keywords in a column: [text:24hourdelivery keywords:24#hour#delivery]

Comment: I don't see anything after your colon there. Was there an error? I'm substantially tired, I might well have made an error. It does produce one record per keyword present in a row, though, as I said in the answer. So if that's what happened, that's what was expected.